# Bit integer value from numerated list

Tags: php, bit

How would one get the integer value of the n-th value from n?

This is hard to phrase so I'll just use English. If I wanted the 3rd integer value from 1...

```
1 = 1
2 = 3
3 = 4 <- (looking to get 4 using 3)
4 = 8
5 = 16 <- (or 16 using 5)
...
```

I could just do a lookup table, but I'm sure there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bitvalue = 5;

$intvalue = 2 ** ($bitvalue - 1);

// gives 16
echo $intvalue;
```

The ** operator is the power operator. So I'm using powers of 2.